# python to php conversion

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to convert parts of a python script into php.  I know most of it, but I've run into something to do with bitshifting (i think?) which I don't have much experience in even in PHP!  Can somebody translate this python function into php please?

```
def setBit(value, position, on):
    if on:
        mask = 1 << position
        return (value | mask)
    else:
        mask = ~(1 << position)
        return (value & mask)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function setBit($value, $position, $on = true) {
    if($on) {
        return $value | (1 << $position);
    }
    return $value & ~(1 << $position);
}
```

Comment: wow, that's just embarrassing, it's like a carbon copy of the python function!  I guess I've just never used the << operator before, anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
function SetBit ($value, $position, $on) {

    if ($on) return ($value|(1<<$position));

    return ($value&(~(1<<$position)));

}
```

Comment: This could be reduced to one line, if you're going to take that approach: `return ($on) ? $value | (1 << $position) : $value & ~(1 << $position);`

Comment: I love that little ternary operator, so good at making code more compact.  My goal wasn't actually one line, my goal was to eliminate intermediary variables.  I hate assigning anything to a variable that isn't going to be used more than once...a hang up of mine...